# Как переименовать копию проекта в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android

На английском стэке задавали тот же вопрос, последовательность действий была примерно следующая:

1. Создать копию проекта используя файловый менеджер.
2. Refactor->Rename для проекта.
3. Изменить Gradle соответствующим образом.

Мои проблемы:

1. Как и что нужно сделать в Gradle?
2. На этапе переименования через Refactor выводит в EventLog следующее:

> 11:40:58 Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: H0001 Practise. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.
>
> 11:40:58 Gradle sync started
>
> 11:41:02 Gradle sync completed
>
> 11:41:02 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
>
> 11:41:03 Gradle build finished in 1s 579ms
>
> 11:41:25 Throwable: Merged rootsChanged not allowed inside rootsChanged, rootsChanged level == 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Чтобы переименовать проект в Android Studio нужно выполнить такие действия:

1. Идем в папку, где лежит проект и меняем имя этой папки на то, которое на необходимо.
2. Открываем Android Studio, в окне приглашения выбираем `Open an existing Android Studio project` и находим папку нашего нового проекта.
3. После открытия в `AndroidManifest.xml` мы видим в двух местах название старого проекта. Эта информация хранится в строковых ресурсах, поэтому переходим в `strings.xml` и меняем имя старого проекта на новое.
4. Имя нашего пакета все еще осталось старое. Идем в папку java, нажимаем на имя нашего пакета правой кнопкой мыши, выбираем Refactor, а потом Rename. После этого выбираем Rename directory и меняем имя нашего пакета.
5. Переходим в файл build.gradle, находим блок defaultConfig и строку applicationID, которая имеет значение нашего старого пакета. Меняем имя пакета и синхронизируем проект.

[Источник](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqa6NyJwA04) информации для ответа.

Comment: Если автору вопроса видео поможет, тогда я согласен переделать свой ответ в текстовую версию, чтобы его было видно для всех ищущих.

Comment: @Kostya ответ должен помогать не только автору вопроса, но и тем, кто придет сюда с той же проблемой. Для них обнаружить через пару месяцев вопрос с отмеченным ответом "вот решение <мертвая ссылка>" будет достаточно неприятно.

Comment: @PashaPash я переделал ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить содержимое файла /.idea/.name

Comment: А на что изменить? Я просто новичек в программировании и еще больший новичек в Android =)

Comment: На новое имя  проекта.

Comment: Увы, не работает. Имя проекта осталось тем же.

Comment: Проект перезагрузили?

Comment: да, перезагружал

Answer (score 0):

Тут три способа, Третий мне помог. 
https://androidride.com/how-to-change-rename-android-app-package-name-android-studio/

Answer (score -1):

После проделанных шагов из 2 ответа, мне ещё необходимо было в MainActivity.java переименовать все вхождения старого имени пакета на новое имя. Так что если у кого после переименования возникают ошибки - проверьте вхождение старого имени пакета в кодах.

Comment: А можно указать правильное решение, а не просто минус ставить? Наверняка я не один тут новичок.